# Sorting Nomenclature

Tags: sorting, nomenclature

I am trying to sort my Nomenclature into strings, Numbers and symbols using the code `\usepackage [stdsubgroups]{nomencl}` in my LaTeX preamble but when I try to view my document I get the error below and I dont know how to fix it. Any suggestions would be really helpful.
[image]

This is also a copy of my preamble:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[stdsubgroups]{nomencl}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother 
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{figure}{part}% Reset figure numbering at every part
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{figure}}% Figure number is part.figure
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\nompreamble{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm} 
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,0.65){
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
{\includegraphics[width=4.205cm, keepaspectratio=true]{NewUCLAN}  }
& {\bf \huge{EI3040 Aerospace Propulsion}} & \bf \huge{2021-22} \end{tabular}}
\end{picture}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the document class?

Comment: @JasperHabicht it is just a standard article class document.

Comment: The document class is considered part of the preamble. It is quite important to know about it, also with which options you load it. If I compile your code, I get no error (apart from the missing image file).